# Django abstract models importing

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some abstract model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    #some filelds...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

When I importing this model like so: `from project.application.models import MyModel` I have this class imported: `<class 'project.application.models.MyModel'>` But when I importing like so: `from application.models import MyModel` I have this class imported without `project` prefix: `<class 'application.models.MyModel'>`

If the model isn't abstract it always imported with `project` prefix: `<class 'project.application.models.MyModel'>`

So when I try to use issubclass function it is leads to strange behavior.

The question is why django abstract models imported in this way and how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: @fastreload The question is why django abstract models imported in this way and how to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

### The explanation

I'm not sure this has something to do with Django or abstract classes, but with how your path is built.

Take the following example:

```
dir0/
    dir1/
        __init__.py 
        dir2/
            __init__.py containing class A
```

Now suppose both `dir0` and `dir1` are on your path, you'll get:

```
>>> from dir2 import B
>>> B
<class 'dir2.B'>
>>> from dir1.dir2 import B
>>> B
<class 'dir1.dir2.B'>
```

### The solution

Luckily, since django 1.4, you don't need anymore path tricks, and this situation should not arise anymore. Only the directory containing your manage.py, as well as your project folder an app folders should be on your path.

You should *always* use `import myapp...` or `from myapp...`, do not use the project in your  imports, it would make your app non-reusable.

You can check out [the django documentation for 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py), which compares the old project layout with the new one.